# Webpack "Invalid configuration object" when using type: "asset/resource"

Tags: javascript, css, image, webpack, assets

I am new to webpack, and am trying to use images for the first time, following [this tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images). My ultimate goal is to be able to refer to an image in CSS, something like this: `background-image: url("assets/bg.png");`

Here is my config.

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./js/main.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "."),
    filename: "public/main.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        // This part does not work:
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

It works without the rule for images, but with it I get the following error when building:

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - configuration.module.rules[2].type should be one of these:
>   "javascript/auto" | "javascript/dynamic" | "javascript/esm" | "json" | "webassembly/experimental"
>   -> Module type to use for the module

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and would really appreciate some tips.

(I'm using Webpack 5.74.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering `type: "asset/resource"` is a valid option for [Webpack 5](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/), double-check you are indeed using Webpack 5.74.0 as intended. Run `npm list webpack` or `yarn list webpack` to verify the installed version. If you have a mismatch or multiple versions, that could be the source of the issue.

If the problem still persists, consider creating a minimal reproducible example, which could be the basis to a buh report, as a Webpack GitHub issue.

You could also consider using [`file-loader`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) as a fallback approach for handling images in older Webpack versions or configurations, though this should not be necessary with Webpack 5 and its asset modules feature.

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./js/main.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"), // Make sure output directory is correctly set
    filename: "main.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource", // That should work as is in Webpack 5
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I checked the versions and realized I had an newer version of webpack installed globally, which gave me the version output that I'm using webpack 5, but locally I had an older version.